# SSIS result set fed in parallel to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, parallel-processing

I currently have 2 stored procedures ...

Stored Proc #1 returns a list of products based on a range of criteria

Stored Proc #2 accepts a single productID and performs some complex query logic and writes the results to a table

My problem is that there are over 30,000 products and going through the result set from stored proc #1 one at a time is too slow and I can't easily integrate an entire batch call into stored procedure #2

**My question is as follows:** Using SSIS is there a way to setup a task that would take the result set from Stored Procedure #1 and call Stored Procedure #2 in parallel with each row.

```
EXAMPLE of Stored Proc 1 result set
-----------------------------------
Product ID
----------
ABC123
XYZ987
AAABBB
CCCDDD
EEEFFF

I need to setup SSIS to call the following in parallel:
-------------------------------------------------------
EXEC StoredProc2 'ABC123'
EXEC StoredProc2 'XYZ987'
EXEC StoredProc2 'AAABBB'
EXEC StoredProc2 'CCCDDD'
EXEC StoredProc2 'EEEFFF'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, that's many executions of SP #2.  You can do it though.

Create a data flow task.  Add an OLE DB Source component to the data flow.  Edit the component and configure it to execute SP #1.  You can view the columns in the editor to see what will be output from the component.

Add an OLE DB Command data flow transformation component.  Create a link from the first component to the OLE DB Command component.  Edit the component and enter the SQL statement that will run SP #2 in the SqlCommand property on the Component Properties tab.  Include question marks (?) for each parameter for the SP.

Select the Column Mappings tab. Associate an Input Column with each parameter.

Comment: thanks for the reply! quick clarification .... does it have to be an OLE DB component? or can it be an ADO.NET component?

Comment: @Scott Vercuski, you can use the ADO.NET source and destinations.  However, there is no ADO.NET version of the OLE DB Command that would run SP #2.

Comment: gotcha ! that's ok ... I'll make adjustments to SP #2 to run under the OLE DB context. Much appreciated !

Comment: is there a way to increase the parallelism with this data flow? It seems like it's executing this one at a time? If possible I'd like it to execute as many of SP#2 as it can at once using the rows from SP #1?

Comment: @Scott vercuski, look at the Conditional Split component.  You can send one set of data through one path and another set through a second path.  The condition is up to you, maybe all even numbered ID values go one way and odd numbered ID values to another path.  Put the Conditional Split after the source.  Create a second OLE DB Command component and configure like the first.  Attach one to first path and the other to second path.  You can do this for more paths.